# GridLayout giving errors, crashing app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout-inflater, grid-layout

I'm pretty new to layouts, but I was able to successfully make a pretty nice looking layout (for a tablet). In Eclipse, it works great. I made it all with the 'target' on Android 4.0 (ICS), but obviously my tablet only runs 3.0 (Honeycomb). When I realised the error, I changed the viewer/editing config to 3.2, but Eclipse won't even display the graphic of the layout anymore, it simply spits out:

```
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
    The following classes could not be found:
    - GridLayout (Change to android.widget.GridLayout, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

The error log pops out:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:84)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:86)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:367)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1317)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1071)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ConfigListener.onConfigurationChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:493)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.onRenderingTargetChange(ConfigurationComposite.java:2192)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.access$4(ConfigurationComposite.java:2157)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite$2.widgetSelected(ConfigurationComposite.java:441)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3629)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3284)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#4CBB17"
android:baselineAligned="false" android:weightSum="5"
>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#4CBB17"
            android:columnCount="7" >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="117dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_row="0" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="101dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="2225dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_row="0" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_row="0" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@drawable/back_small" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@drawable/back_small" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@drawable/back_small" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@drawable/back_small" />
        </GridLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#4CBB17"
            android:columnCount="9" >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_row="1" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Next" />

        </GridLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="207dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/blackButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/blackbutton" android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/redButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="202dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/redbutton" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ultimately, I'm able to install the app on my tablet, but it just crashes right away with this from LogCat:

```
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.ajwest.irishpoker/ca.ajwest.irishpoker.IrishPokerActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1741)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1757)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4002)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:459)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:728)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:247)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1771)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at ca.ajwest.irishpoker.IrishPokerActivity.onCreate(IrishPokerActivity.java:30)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1705)
    10-29 23:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(14135):    ... 11 more
```

Will re-making the whole layout with 2.3 selected fix this problem? That's sooo sucky...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GridLayout was introduced in Android 4.0. You can't use it in 3.0 or 3.2.

Comment: BAAHHH!! That really sucks. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Now that the Ice Cream Sandwich sources became available I had a look to see if it would be possible to use the newly introduced GridLayout on pre-4.0. And it is indeed possible. See my blog post about it at http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/11/using-new-gridlayout-on-pre-ice-cream.html